# Adding auto increment column for IDs from differents tables using UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql, jstree

I have seen that in SQL Server there is a function called **[ROW_NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129907/adding-auto-increment-extra-column-to-view-which-is-not-present-in-table-in-sql)**, in my case I am joining 3 tables and each one has different names for the ID column (this I am doing for the **[jsTree plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result/8587437#link-post-22687777)**)

I have this code:

```
$sql= "(SELECT
                c1.idcarrera AS id,
                c1.nombre as text,
                null as parent_id
        FROM siiupv.carrera AS c1)";
$sql.=" UNION ALL ";
$sql.= " (SELECT
                pe.idplan_estudios AS id,
                pe.clave AS text,
                pe.idcarrera as parent_id
        FROM siiupv.plan_estudios AS pe)";
$sql.=" UNION ALL ";
$sql.= " (SELECT idcarga AS id, c2.clave AS text, idplan_estudios as parent_id FROM siiupv.carga AS c2)";
$qResults = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$qResults->execute();
$count = $qResults->rowCount();
while($m = $qResults->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;'.$m["id"].'</td><td>'.$m["text"].'</td><td>'.$m["parent_id"].'</td></tr>';
}
```

It produces this output:

```
+------+------------------+
| id   | text | parent_id |
+------+------------------+
|    1 |  A1  | NULL      |
|    2 |  A2  | NULL      |
|    3 |  A3  | NULL      |
|    1 |  B1  |   1       |
|    2 |  B2  |   2       |
|    3 |  B3  |   1       |
|    4 |  B4  |   2       |
|    5 |  B5  |   5       |
|    1 |  C1  |   4       | Note! (Child of "B4")
|    2 |  C2  |   4       | Note! (Child of "B4")
+------+------------------+
```

But I want to get:

```
+------+------------------+
| id   | text | parent_id |
+------+------------------+
|    1 |  A1  | NULL      |
|    2 |  A2  | NULL      |
|    3 |  A3  | NULL      |
|    4 |  B1  |   1       |
|    5 |  B2  |   2       |
|    6 |  B3  |   1       |
|    7 |  B4  |   2       |
|    8 |  B5  |   5       |
|    9 |  C1  |   7       | Note! (Child of "B4")
|   10 |  C2  |   7       | Note! (Child of "B4")
+------+------------------+
```

**Note!** > The IDs are traversed and therefore must have value `7`

*I would like get help at least of auto increment IDs*

Comment: You could just use a incrementing variable: `$row = 0;` before the loop then `++$row` for the current row number. Note however, that there is no correlation between this id and any database row, it's just a dumb counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to add a row number to each record of the resultset is to use a session variable :

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) id, -- t.id
    t.text,
    t.parent_id
FROM (
    SELECT c1.idcarrera AS id, c1.nombre as text, null as parent_id FROM siiupv.carrera AS c1 ORDER BY c1.id
    UNION ALL SELECT pe.idplan_estudios AS id, pe.clave AS text, pe.idcarrera as parent_id FROM siiupv.plan_estudios AS pe ORDER BY c1.id
    UNION ALL SELECT idcarga AS id, c2.clave AS text, idplan_estudios as parent_id FROM siiupv.carga AS c2 ORDER BY c1.id
) t
```

Comment: it runs fine in phpMyAdmin but not in PHP but I had to enclose each SELECT between () because it marked mysql error # 1221 because of UNION & ORDER BY. your idea is coming but I think it's the session that I can not interpret with php

Comment: Ok, I added a variable at the end with an Alias, now everything is fine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354929/how-to-print-row-number-in-mysql-in-php-application

".... ) t, (SELECT @row_number := 0) r  "

Comment: for the column "parent_id" as I do to add the total spaces where the value is NULL, I mean, I want to change 4 to 7 (without those that are NULL stop being NULL), any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really got the issue but you could generate a new unique id by prefixing it or something.

SELECT CONCAT("A-", idcarga) AS id, c2.clave AS text, CONCAT("A-", idplan_estudios) as parent_id